# FullCalendar - Exibir apenas a data de eventos

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, calendar

Alguém sabe se no [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) tem como fazer aparecer apenas a data dos eventos no calendário.
Assim como aparece no exemplo da imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc tem alguma característica especifica do fullcalendar?Pergunto pq vc printou o calendário do jquery. Não seria melhor utilizar esse plugin, ou customizar esse plugin para atender?

Comment: Esse outro calendário que printei foi da net. Então o fullcalendar é bem simples de mexer, mas não achei essa opção. Queria que ele marcase o dia e não aparecer um monte de evento no mesmo dia. Porque dai quando o usuário clicar na data eu mandaria ele para um filtro por data.

Comment: Da uma olha aqui: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Pretty-Event-Calendar-with-jQuery/